# What additional axiom to GARP do we need to generate a differentiable or smooth utility function

Tags: microeconomics, game-theory, decision-theory, theory, demand

After researching for a while, I find this:

https://www.jstor.org/stable/1913607?seq=2#metadata_info_tab_contents

They come up with an axiom called SSARP that generates a preference with smooth demand function. But what about smooth utility function? What axiom can guarantee that?

---

The axiom should be best on the demand data set just like GARP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None if the axiom is to be on preferences, as any smooth utility representation can be monotone transformed into a non-smooth utility function.

Comment: Well, if it is on the binary relation $\succsim$, then I believe Debreu has an axiom: for any $y$, set $\{x|x\sim y\}$ is of class $\mathcal C^k$.

Comment: @HighGPA Not sure why you are referring to this, seems like it is about the indifference curves, not the utility representation.

Comment: To my limited understanding Debreu proved that having $C^k$ indifference hypersurface is equivalent to k-differentiable utility when $k=2$.

Comment: Debreu defined that a preference is of class $C^2$ if the set $\{x|x\sim y\}$ is of class $C^2$. Along with other axioms such as monotonicity, continuity, completeness and transitivity, the preference relation is represented with a second differentiable utility

Comment: @HighGPA I am afraid there is a slight difference. This preference relation *can* be represented by a $C^2$ utility function. It can also be represented by other utility functions. So I guess your question is not when the utility function is *guaranteed* to be smooth, but when a smooth utility function that represents the preferences *exists*.

Comment: Well, Debreu's conditions on binary relations is both sufficient and necessary.  Regarding my original question on finite demand data sets: yes, the existence of smooth preference is enough.